# Is it safe to remove .one() event handler in jQuery by explicitly calling .off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Event handlers in jQuery that are added using `.on()` can be removed with `.off()` method. How about [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which is executed at most once per event. Can it be removed safely with `.off()` method (for a corner case)?

**Update** :

Specifically want to know if there will be any side effects e.g. memory leak if a self removing event handler is removed explicitly.

```
function loadObject(e){
    if $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('condition'){
        //Corner case - execute the unload function & remove the handler
        unloadObject();
        removeCloseHandler();
    }else {
        //Do more stuff
        addCloseHandler();
    }
}

function removeCloseHandler(){
    $('body').off('click', unloadObject);
}

function addCloseHandler(myObj){
    $('body').one('click', myObj, unloadObject);
}

function addOpenHandler(){
    $('#myid').on('click', '.myclass', loadObject);
}
```

**P.S.** I know I can use `.on()` & `.off()` instead of `.one()` however I am curious about the usage of `.off()` with `.one()`

Comment: Could you point to the docs or did you conclude from the source code?

Comment: I spent ten seconds testing it -> http://jsfiddle.net/QRZ6Z/, like you should have.

Comment: one is self removing i believe

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for testing it out. However, I'm worried about any side effects e.g. memory leak etc. hence want to verify it beyond that `it works`

Comment: we need to see your code to verify. However, please remember that internally, `.one` uses `.on`, so by using `.one`, you are using `.on`, therefore it stands to reason that `.off` will work just as well with `.one` as it does with `.on`

Comment: I can guarantee that `one()` and `on()` are exactly the same, the only thing `one()` does internally is call `on()`

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.one

Comment: Do you want to remove a *specific* `one`-handler? All handlers of a type/namespace are easily removed.

Comment: You are correctly removing the event handler. I don't know of another way to state that that would be any more clear.

Comment: @adeneo: But what `on` does internally when the `one` flag is set is totally different…

Comment: @Bergi - It's not "totally" different, it just calls `off()` when the `on()` event handler is triggered.

Comment: @Bergi : You had an interesting argument but you've removed your answer. Curious to know why?

Comment: the last line in my answer's code snippet takes care of the issue he was presenting. By setting the new function's guid to the same as the old one, unbinding using the old function also removes the special function jquery created with .one

Comment: Internally when you unbind an event handler by passing in the original function, jquery pulls the function.guid property to figure out which event handler needs to be removed. Since both the original function and the special one jquery created have the same guid, using either will properly remove the event.

Comment: @buffer: The functions are not compared by reference, but by their `.guid` property. See Kevin's comments and the code in his answer - I had been blind to miss the line (and the explicit comment).

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates it. http://jsfiddle.net/tAuDA/3/ I'm able to unbind the event using an entirely different, unrelated function by simply moving the guid around. :)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for challenging that and digging in more, i learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically want to know if there will be any side effects e.g. memory leak if a self removing event handler is removed explicitly

No, there will not be.

This is the important part of the .on method that handles this:

```
if (one === 1) { // if it was called from `$.fn.one`
    origFn = fn;
    fn = function (event) {
        // Can use an empty set, since event contains the info
        jQuery().off(event);
        return origFn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    // Use same guid so caller can remove using origFn
    fn.guid = origFn.guid || (origFn.guid = jQuery.guid++);
}
```

The only difference between a `.on` bound event and a `.one` bound event is that `.one` gets a special callback that when called unbinds the event and then executes the original callback.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Memory leak would only occur if the event handler was not removed and the bound elements were removed from the DOM in such a way that they could not be accessed again.

Comment: Note however that will only affect elements removed from the dom by something other than jquery, or by jquery's `.detatch` method (since all other jquery dom manip methods properly clean up events and data before removing). Another exception may be moving an element from the DOM to a DOM Fragment that never gets removed.